# Trying to get an applause sound to play when jframe opens

Tags: swing, jframe, wav

First i will say i have my Jframe opening and staying open for 10 seconds.
I wrote some games for kids to display to them what a future in programming could be or computer science... anyway

Whomever wins I have another Jframe designed to pop up when it does i would like a sound clip to play. Currently the sound clip is in the source folder and i have a little method to play it but it is not working. Here is the code

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class HoorayWithTimer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

int counter;

public HoorayWithTimer() {
    initComponents();


    Clip click = clipOpen("applause3.wav");// should open the clip
    clipStart(click);


}//end of public HorrayWithTimer()
/*
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    timerLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(571, 410));
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    getContentPane().add(timerLabel);
    timerLabel.setBounds(632, 411, 66, 29);
    timerLabel.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("timerLabel");

    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/party_balloons_scaled.png"))); // NOI18N
    getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
    jLabel1.setBounds(0, 0, 560, 540);

    Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       HoorayWithTimer.this.setVisible(false);
       HoorayWithTimer.this.dispose();
    }
    });
    timer.start();


    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
private Clip clipOpen(String name)// method to play clip
{
    URL url = getClass().getResource(name);
    try {
        AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(stream);
        return clip;
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
    }

    return null;
}

private void clipStart(Clip clip) {
    clip.start();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HoorayWithTimer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HoorayWithTimer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HoorayWithTimer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HoorayWithTimer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>



    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new HoorayWithTimer().setVisible(true);

        }
    });

}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel timerLabel;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: its actually for a service learning project for school

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here `clipOpen("applause3.wav")`. Try to use `/applause3.wav`. Also where is your wav file? For example it works for my path `"/res/1.mp3"`, `1.mp3` file exists in `res` folder in folder `src`.

EDIT: Replace your code and watch exception, it's here not in `clipStart` method:

```
private Clip clipOpen(String name){
URL url = getClass().getResource(name);
try {
    AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(stream);
    return clip;
} catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace()
}

return null;
}
```

Comment: the wav file is just in the src folder.

Comment: even with the / i am getting a bunch of null pointer exceptios that all go away when i remove   Clip click = clipOpen("/applause3.wav");
                    clipStart(click);

Comment: where is your exceptions?

Comment: I think you have another exception, in `clipOpen` add in catch block `ex.printStackTrace();` and see your error

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at HoorayWithTimer.clipStart(HoorayWithTimer.java:97)
 at HoorayWithTimer.<init>(HoorayWithTimer.java:39)
 at HoorayWithTimer$2.run(HoorayWithTimer.java:133)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)

Comment: at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 8 seconds)

Comment: again all these go away when i remove

Comment: Clip click = clipOpen("/applause3.wav"); clipStart(click);

Comment: do you add `ex.printStackTrace();` to see real exception, because of it your `clipOpen` return null and in `clipStart` you hav your errors. use Debugger !

Comment: added another catch block

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at HoorayWithTimer.clipStart(HoorayWithTimer.java:100)
 at HoorayWithTimer.<init>(HoorayWithTimer.java:39)
 at HoorayWithTimer$2.run(HoorayWithTimer.java:136)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)

Comment: at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)